# Is my Acer dead? Can I do anything to save it?

Tags: maple

[image]

Is my Acer dead? It had a few leaves on it but now nothing. Is there anything that I can do to help it come back?

[image]

Comment: Need to look closely at the twigs. Are they all dry and dead? Are there buds?

Comment: think i may need to upload a new question with a better photo, not sure i can upload a photo in the comments.

Comment: The word "edit" is available under your question. You can use that. Take the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suppose it's dead. But the cost of giving it some more time is very low.

Try watering it when the soil is dry and let it have a month or so. If it does not come back after a couple weeks of warm sunny days then it's dead.

Comment: thank you for your response,  i shall give that a go. nothing to loose i guess, already had my upset days over her lol ( she was a gift when she was just a tiny twig) lol.

Comment: +1 Would have advised to shallowly knife-cut the base but Your approach is superior.